# HTML table wordwrap in table with server data

Tags: php, html, mysqli, html-table, word-wrap

I have a table which is filled with data from my server. For each row are 250 characters allowed.

This drives into the problem that some cells could be have a very long witdh.
Now I want limit the characters in each row to a specific amount.

Do not know how to solve it. Maybe CSS or PHP function?

My code:

```
<html>
 <head></head>

 <body>
<table name = "userDetails">
    <tr>
        <th>id</th>
        <th>Gleitzeitrahmen</th>
        <th>Abweichungen</th>
        <th>Mehrarbeitervolumen</th>
        <th>Mehrarbeit</th>
        <th>Ausgleich</th>
        <th>Mehrarbeit</th>
        <th>Personalmassnahmen</th>
        <th>Ueberstunden_abzusehen</th>
        <th>Klaerungsbedarfe</th>
        <th>Klaerungsbedarfe</th>

    </tr>
<?php
$servername = "localhost";
$username = "root";
$password = "";  //your database password
$dbname = "quartalsuebersicht";  //your database name

$con = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);

if ($con->connect_error) {
    die("Connection failed: " . $con->connect_error);
}
else
{
    //echo ("Connect Successfully");
}

 $sql_table_main = "SELECT id,name_Gleitzeitrahmen, name_Abweichungen, name_Mehrarbeitervolumen, name_Mehrarbeit1, name_Ausgleich, name_Mehrarbeit2, name_Personalmassnahmen, name_Ueberstunden_abzusehen, name_Klaerungsbedarfe1, name_Klaerungsbedarfe2 FROM dashboard";

        $result_table_main = mysqli_query($con, $sql_table_main);
        if(mysqli_num_rows($result_table_main) > 0){

            while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result_table_main)) {
                echo '<tr>';
                echo '<td>'. $row['id'] .'</td>';
                echo '<td>'. $row['name_Gleitzeitrahmen'] .'</td>';
                echo '<td>'. $row['name_Abweichungen'] .'</td>';
                echo '<td>'. $row['name_Mehrarbeitervolumen'] .'</td>';
                echo '<td>'. $row['name_Mehrarbeit1'] .'</td>';
                echo '<td>'. $row['name_Ausgleich'] .'</td>';
                echo '<td>'. $row['name_Mehrarbeit2'] .'</td>';
                echo '<td>'. $row['name_Personalmassnahmen'] .'</td>';
                echo '<td>'. $row['name_Ueberstunden_abzusehen'] .'</td>';
                echo '<td>'. $row['name_Klaerungsbedarfe1'] .'</td>';
                echo '<td>'. $row['name_Klaerungsbedarfe2'] .'</td>';
                echo '</tr>';
            }
        }
?>
</table>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is my approach using css

```css
th{
  
   max-width : 30px;
  white-space : nowrap;
  overflow : hidden;
}
```

```html
<table name = "userDetails">
    <tr>
        <th >id</th>
        <th >Gleitzeitrahm</th>
        <th>Abweichungen</th>
        <th>Mehrarbeitervolumen</th>
        <th>Mehrarbeit</th>
        <th>Ausgleich</th>
        <th>Mehrarbeit</th>
        <th>Personalmassnahmen</th>
        <th>Ueberstunden_abzusehen</th>
        <th>Klaerungsbedarfe</th>
        <th>Klaerungsbedarfe</th>

    </tr>
    </table>
```